# How to access property which is not saved in Realm database

Tags: swift, realm

I've got an object which consists of couple of properties and I would like to access one property which is just temporary value and doesn't need to be saved in the database.

```
class Item: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var eid: Int = 0
    // ...
    var isAccessible: Bool = false

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case eid, isAccessible
    }

    required convenience init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.eid = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .eid)
        self.isAccessible = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isAccessible) ?? false
    }
}
```

Of course when I save this object and then load data from the Realm it doesn't include `isAccessible`. After changing it to `@objc dynamic var` it requires to use `write`. The problem is that it's a list inside other list. I also tried copying the object using `.init(value: )`

Answer (score 0):

Ignored properties of Realm objects only persist as long as the object exists in memory. As soon as you save an object to Realm, then retrieve it, that retrieved object will different than your original one even though all of its **stored** properties will be the same as that of your original object.

You should only use ignored properties if you can make sure that they will only be needed for the duration of the lifetime of your object. In your case its clear that you either need to increase the lifetime of your object to keep it in memory as long as you need access to the temporary variable's value or change the temporary variable to a stored property.